# Django CharField unique argument in new Django version

Tags: python, django

In my forms.py file I am using CharField. I read about unique argument of CharField in the book: it says if the unique argument = True, then that model's CharField cannot repeat. In the book Django 2.1 version is presented. As for now, the argumen's name has been changed. I think so because Django shows an error sign `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'unique'`

Comment: Where did you put the `unique`? in models? or forms?

Comment: I mean like this 'username = CharField(unique=True)'

Comment: how did you import that `CharField` ?

Comment: from django import forms

forms.CharField()

Comment: oops forms not models

Comment: The `unique` parameter is for model's `CharField`, not for forms.

Comment: than what argument can i use for username to be not repeated?

Comment: @someseeapeniseeaharpoon you need to **add form validation to your username field** to check if the username already exists or not. Of course, the error would be shown only after you submit the form. If you want to check if the username already exists before submitting the form, you would need to add JQuery AJAX script also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To validate uniqueness in a form, you could use the forms [`clean_fieldname()` methods](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/validation/) to make an extra DB query before saving the form.

```
from django import forms
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

class MyForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField()

    def clean_username(self):
        if MyModel.objects.filter(username=self.cleaned_data['username'])\
                .exists():
            raise ValidatioError('already exists')
```

---

Or if it should be a `ModelForm`:

```
from django import forms
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from .models import MyModel
 
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ['username', ]

    def clean_username(self):
        if self._meta.model.objects\
                .filter(username=self.cleaned_data['username'])\
                .exists():
            raise ValidatioError('already exists')
```

Comment: but how can i check in views?

Comment: @someseeapeniseeaharpoon I don't understand your question. The form is used in the view, so the validation is done in the view. Or what are you asking?